# Searching for specific text within column of data

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to write an Excel macro where I have an example data set like shown below. This data is located in `Sheet1` of Excel.

```
BG.   test1  743,
DF.   test2  34,
GH.   test3  20,
DF.   test4  29, and
WS.   test5  3
```

I am looking to copy only the specific cells that contain data with `BG.   test1`, `GH.   test3  20`, and `DF.   test4  29`.

```
Sub test()
'
' testing Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'

For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("A:A")
    If Cell.Value = "BG.   test1" Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If lastRow > 1 Then lastRow = lastRow + 1
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & lastRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I was able to pull the row that contained `BG.   test1`, but I am unable to pull the other two rows as I am getting an error.

Comment: which error?  have you googled the error?

Comment: Two quick points. Please give the details of the error. And void using 'Select' in general. It can be done away with in most cases.

Comment: The error I'm receiving is Can't execute code in break mode.

Comment: Then take the code out of break mode.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
Sub test()
'
' testing Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
lrow = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
i = lrow
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("A:A")
If Cell.Value = "BG.   test1" Or Cell.Value = "GH.   test3  20" or Cell.Value= "DF.   test4  29"Then

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value = cell.EntireRow.Value
     i = i + 1      

End If
Next
End Sub
```

Here it will verify Column A of Sheet 1 and if our search string matched then it will get the entire roe to the next sheet.

Thank You

Comment: Trying this macro, I am receiving an error that says "Subscript out of range". Regarding the following row:  lrow = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Comment: Make sure you are having two sheets in your work book, Sheet1, Sheet2 and then execute this code with  "BG.   test1" value in column A

Comment: It says variable not defined for lrow = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Comment: Use Dim lrow As long and then try executing

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

'"BG.   test1","GH.   test3  20", "DF.   test4  29"

I have gone with Instr to check if that string is in the cell otherwise you could have used

```
If test = "BG.   test1" Or test = "GH.   test3  20" Or test = "DF.   test4  29" Then
```

Using union is an efficient way to write out your rows in one go.

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetRows()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim loopRange As Range
Dim unionRange As Range
Dim currentCell As Range
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow2 As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set loopRange = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

For Each currentCell In loopRange

    Dim test As String

    test = currentCell.Text

    If InStr(1, test, "BG.   test1") > 0 _
     Or InStr(1, test, "GH.   test3  20") > 0 _
     Or InStr(1, test, "DF.   test4  29") > 0 Then

        If Not unionRange Is Nothing Then
            Set unionRange = Union(unionRange, currentCell.EntireRow)
        Else
            Set unionRange = currentCell.EntireRow
        End If
    End If

    Next currentCell

    If Not unionRange Is Nothing Then
    unionRange.Copy ws2.Range("A" & IIf(lastRow2 = 1, 1 ,lastRow2+ 1))
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The error I'm receiving is Can't execute code in break mode

Comment: that is not in relation to code I posted - I think. Have you pushed a button that has applied a break?

Comment: try pressing F5 to resume running

Comment: it adds rows to the bottom of sheet1. I will edit for sheet.

Comment: Says Variable not defined for: lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row        ........ sorry I'm new to this and don't really understand how to fix the errors :)

Comment: Apologies. I have edited. It should have  Dim lastRow2 As Long
     at top.

Comment: I'm really sorry. Subscript out of range?    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Comment: you wanted data to go in sheet 2. What is the name of your sheet2?  Change that line to Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("your2ndsheetnamegoeshere")

Comment: That's what I don't understand because "Sheet2" is already created and empty

Comment: Then I suspect your given strings don’t match the ones I have put. Try using the other version of if I gave

Comment: Or better still check the values are the same as mine for BG etc. Insert your values as are and test

Comment: What is "test" referring to here?  Dim test As String

    test = currentCell.Text   ..... this may be the issue?

Comment: test is the value of the cell. It is more efficient to hold it in a variable than to keep going back to the sheet. Either the wrong place is being searched or the wrong value is being searched for. If you put in Debug.Print loopRange.Address that will tell you which range in sheet 1 is being looped. If that is correct, check each search string is correct e.g. is "BG.   test1  743" correct?